# Redirect to sign-in page if not authorized in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

I have Devise and CanCan in my Rails app. I think by default, it should redirect users to sign-in page if users try to login to unauthorized page. But somehow, it doesn't work for my app.

How to I implement a checking if users are authorized and redirect to home if not globally (i.e., for all controllers/methods)?

**UPDATE:** It seems that my CanCan doesn't work anymore after updating jquery.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, show us your `routes.rb` file. To check just add `before_filter :authenticate_member!` on top of your controller class.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it (in routes.rb) with my own custom authentication (probably similar with devise):

```
root :to => '<controller#action_needing_authorization>', :constraints => lambda{|req| !req.session[:user_id].blank? }
root :to => 'sessions#new'
```

This works because routes are matched in the order they're specified.